# How do I find data attributes for images in a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image

I need to use jQuery to manipulate a bunch of images I show on the page that have an added html5 data attribute.  How would I get the data values for value1 and value2 for all the images that have them, but ignore any image that does not.  In other words, I need to cycle through all images on a page looking for the presence of these attributes.

Here's the code that displays the images:

```
<% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(picture.photo.url(:full),  
              :class => "picture_list_item",
              :data => {:value1 => picture.value1, :value2 => picture.value2}, 
              :id => "picture_" + picture.id.to_s),
              picture_path(:id => picture.id) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery should make this pretty painless.

```
$("img[data]").each(function(){
    //do something with each individual image.
});
```

Or just this:

```
$("img[data]").doSomething();
//doSomething to all.
```

This should select all images with a data attribute.  You can work with all of them at once, or use `.each()` to work with the selected images one at a time.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/SLdk4/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add a class representing each of those values and then can you manipulate them using class selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#parent img[data]').each(function(){
       var data = $(this).attr('data').split(',');
       var data_1 = data[0];                         // retrieve first data
       var data_2 = data[1];                         // retrieve second data
       console.log( data_1 +' '+ data_2 );           // or use 'alert' to test
});
```

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/CXcG4/1/)*

[.each()](http://api.jquey.com/each)
[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)
[.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)